# How do i make the header/footer extend width-wise to fit the screen, and the main content extend height-wise to fit the screen?

Tags: css

I have tried everything! I simply cannot get my website to look the way i want it to.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to SilmanServer!</title>
<link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="pageHeader"> 
<h1>SilmanServer</h1>
<p>Aaron Silman's Personal Home Server </p>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="./projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>


<div id="main">

<div>
<h2>What the hell?</h2>
<p>
This the project I embarked on around June of 2012 with an old computer that I had at home. My goal: To transform that old, useless HP Pavilion a6750y into a fully functioning webserver for this website! Along the way I also learned (X)HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP, MySQL and a bunch of other things needed for designing and developing websites, as well as administrating my own server.
</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2> Why? </h2>
<p>
As mentioned before, I really wanted to learn how to build websites that function both on the client side and server side. I wanted to just play around and learn. So I started learning, beginning with the basics. I will also use this website as documentation, tracking my progress and noting a lot of important steps so if anyone (including myself - in case I forget) wants a guide to setting up a server and learning web design and development they an refer to <a href="./guide_to_the_web.html">this page </a> for a complete, idiot-proof, guide to the web from scratch.
</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="pageFooter">

<p> This is a footer
</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

/* CSS Reset*/
/* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

/* Global Styles */
html{
    background: url(./images/sway.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat::no-repeat;

    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background: #3ee; /*<-------------- problem here bro */
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
}


#pageheader, #pageFooter {
    float:left;
    min-width:100%;
} 

/*Header Styles*/

#pageHeader{
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family::"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    background-color: #0F6; 
}

#pageHeader p{
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: .5em;
    font-family::"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

/*Body Styles*/

/*Navigation styles */

#navigation{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    float: left;
    background-color: #C09;
    position: inherit;
}

#navigation li{
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

#navigation a:hover{
    color: #91BED4;
}


/* Main Content */

#main{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#F00;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFF
}

/* Footer */

#pageFooter{
    height: 150px;
    background: #00F;
    color:#CF0;
    font-size: 2em;
    /*position:fixed;
    bottom:0;*/
}
```

As you can see i color coded the different sections in order to see what is being affected by what. For some reason the navigations div color isnt showing up and instead it is taking on the color of the body. I  want this page to have a header and footer which extends to fill the screens witdh and a main content block that has a minimum height of the screen size but the min-height specification just isnt working.

What can i do to fix this? What are some useful techniques for what i am trying to do? I am new to CSS and any advice is useful!

Here is what the website looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r95E.jpg

I just cant seem to get the red box to have a minimum height of the screen.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `float: left` which is causing the `background-color` line to be ignored.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much for that! I edited the original post and that fixes the problem of color not matching the navigation, but the main content still doesn't have a min width of the full screen. What do i do about that?

Comment: check this out, is that the desired behaviour? http://jsfiddle.net/pdF4g/1/

Comment: Yes, That is almost exactly what i want with the exception that i want the nagivation (purple box) and main content (red box) to be 60% screen width and centered with margin: 0 auto. As you can see there is a width: 60% in the #main block that isn't shrinking its width.

Also how did you come to learn CSS? I am having trouble advancing my learning because i run into these problems and have no idea how to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for here, the header and footer are working fine width-wise for me.

As for height, are you trying to get the footer to stay on the bottom despite a small amount of content? Try Googling "css sticky footer". There are a few out there so play around with them and learn how they work.

Comment: I am trying to make the red box extend until downward with blank content until the bottom of the footer his the bottom of the page and if their is more than enough content to scroll past one page i want it to just be at the bottom of the main content.

Comment: Yep, you need a sticky footer. It's a bit more tricky in css than it should be but follow the tutorials and you'll be fine.

Comment: why won't min-height: 100% work in this scenario? I am asking to learn more about CSS as i am very new. I want to understand why applying a minimum height to the main content wont push the footer to the bottom, in fact, its not working at all. Thanks for the advice, btw!

Comment: Percentages don't work that way. Don't worry, most people make that mistake when they start.

100% means 100% of the content of the element, NOT the containing div. So, if you have a element that is 20px tall and you apply height:100% then you make it 100% of 20px, which is 20px.

You're trying to make it 100% of the div that it's in, so that doesn't help.

Comment: i see what you are saying, so when i was reading to add min-height: 100% i think it was referring to the body, which is inside the html tag, so they actually get the 100% screen effect, whereas i do not since my main is inside the body tag. 

i uncommented the lines at the bottom of #pageFooter which says position:fixed; bottom:0; but that just places the footer on the bottom without extending the body and main.

But if i put min-height inside the body tag and the main content tag i feel as though it should work, but instead it only extends the blue body box, not the red main content one.

Answer (score 0):

Because the width part in CSS has #header id but in the code you use pageHeader.

Comment: Thanks for that heads up, i made the changes in the code and the original post reflects that but i am still getting a problem. This is what it looks like right now, and i am trying to get the red box to have a minimujm height of the screen size: http://imgur.com/OIuad